# How can I loop through all sub folder of FolderA and execute o.bat in each when I execute a.bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I loop through all sub folders of `FolderA` and execute `o.bat` in each when I execute `a.bat`?

```
/FolderA/a.bat
/FolderA/FolderB/o.bat
/FolderA/FolderC/o.bat
/FolderA/FolderD/o.bat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b') do start %%f\o.bat
```

If you need to run the batch file from elsewhere then specify the path to foldera like:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b c:\foldera\') do start %%f\o.bat
```